# Activating bounding box for a volumetrics

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, volumetrics

is there a way to make volumetrics a basic bounding box in solid view mode? it keeps blocking out all the other objects in my scene so i always need to keep turning off and when when i need to access the insides

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just go to the *Object Properties* and under *Viewport Display* > *Display As* choose *Bounds* instead of *Textured*:

[image: display as bounds]

If you now want to make sure that you are not selecting the volume by accident when you actually wanted to select something else, you can go to the *Outliner* and in the filter (the funnel symbol) enable the *Selectable* toggle. Then you can disable selectability of the volume object afterwards.

[image: disable selectability]

Comment: thanks a bunch, man

Comment: @KelvinColeman No need to thank me, but if this helped you might consider accepting the answer? Read more about it here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)